# IPhone Compile Error Problem

Tags: iphone

I have created sample code in iphone and its work fine , When i was working in normal speed..
When i work fast or click the uibutton many times faster that app get crashed or hanged...

In that log

[Session started at 2009-07-16 01:08:01 -0400.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-966) (Tue Mar 10 02:43:13 UTC 2009)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 15423.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: This is not the log. this is just some info which shows up in gdb. there must be a statement which tells you where the error is

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into how to use GDB.

For starters, you might want to type:
help

at the prompt to see available commands.  But, off the top of my head:
bt

will show you a backtrace of the crash.  If it doesn't show you the actual files involved, but instead shows you a list of numbers, type:
x #

for the smaller numbers in the list.  (The really large numbers are references to objects in the iPhone SDK which *probably* won't help you, since it's not your code.)